Ubuntu Server in vmplayer does not show nerd font symbols when I login
Issue: nerd font symbols not displaying in a vanilla install of Ubuntu Server in VM Player when I login directly. However, when I ssh into the same server using Ubuntu Desktop (installed in wsl), it works.
ssh to ubuntu server

echo $SHELL /bin/bash
echo $TERM linux
who am i ubuntu-server pts/0 2024-11-21 14:05 (192.168.xxx.xxx)

ubuntu server

echo $SHELL /bin/bash
echo $TERM xterm-256color
who am i ubuntu-server tty1 2024-11-21 xx:xx

VM Player
OS: Ubuntu Sever 24.04
Steps to reproduce the issue

Install Ubuntu Server in VM Player
update server
Install starship
reboot and login
symbols do not show up

I have attached two screen captures

ssh_ubuntu_server.jpg - screen capture of ssh into ubuntu server
ubuntu_server_vmplayer.jpg - screen capture of logging into ubuntu server (installed in VM)

If anyone can help me understand why this is happening, that would be really appreciated.
I installed the fonts to ~/.local/share/fonts using the instructions provided on How to Install Nerd Fonts on Linux
